# HTTP request based on timestamp using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to send HTTP requests using jmeter for which I am using a HTTP sampler. The http requests have a parameter TaskID and these parameters read from a CSV file. I just wanted to make changes on how the HTTP request will be send.

The CSV file looks like this

```
Time TaskID
9000 42353456
9000 53463464
9000 65475787
9300 42354366
9300 23423535
9600 43545756
9600 53463467
9600 23435346
```

Now I want to send request based on the Time. For example in Time 9000 there are 3 TaskID. So I want to send 3 HTTP requests with those TaskIDs at a time. Similarly for the other Times as well. Any idea on how to do it?

Update:
[image]

Comment: I do not understand whether your "Time" is just a way of grouping TaskIDs or if you actually talk about time as in "3 TaskIDs after 9000 seconds, 2 TaskIDs another 300 seconds later, ...". Could you please clarify!

Comment: It is just a way to group TaskIDs. I am not calculating it.

Answer (score 1):

I created a minimal working example for one possible solution.

[image]

Basically I read the csv in a JSR223 Sampler and group it with following groovy code in "read csv" sampler:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer

current_dir = FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir().replace("\\","/")
csv_lines = new File(current_dir + "/test.csv").readLines()

times = []

csv_lines.each { line ->
    line = line.split(",")
    time = line[0]
    task_id = line[1]
    if (vars.getObject(time)){
        tasks = vars.getObject(time)
        tasks.add(task_id)
        vars.putObject(time, tasks)
    }
    else{
        times.add(time)
        vars.putObject(time, [task_id])
    }
}

times.eachWithIndex { time, i ->
    vars.put("time_" + (i+1), time)
    }
```

Notes:

- (i+1) is used because the ForEach Controller will not consider the 0th element
- I used "," as csv separator and omitted the header line
- the "initialize task_ids" sampler holds following code:

.

```
time = vars.get("time")
tasks = vars.getObject(time)
   
tasks.eachWithIndex {task, i ->
    vars.put(time + "_" + (i+1), task)
}
```

I hope, this helps!

Comment: That is just a [Dummy Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/) with `${task}` as its name to "visualize" the result in ResultTreeView.

Comment: I am not clear on how to send the HTTP request here. I used to provide the IP of the server in the HTTP request sampler. Here where should I specify the IP?

Comment: Hey. Sorry for the late answer: your are supposed to replace the Dummy Sampler by the appropriately configured HTTP Sampler. I just used the Dummy Sampler to show the expected outcome: that you have the desired values in a JMeter variable for further use.

Comment: Can you please check if this is the way I should configure the http sampler. I have added it as an update to my question.

Comment: It could work this way. What you would get would be something like "http://172.17.66.177?_id=${task}". Is that what you want? You can put it into the "path" or the "body" or a header as well -> this really depends on the application you are trying to test! Just hit RUN and have a look at the request in the Result Tree and adapt it to what you observed in your browser/fiddler/whereever.